# Char doesn't show in .dat file in C

Tags: c

I am trying to write some records (patient info) into a .dat file using C. The patient info contains the National ID no., name, gender and the telephone no.

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char order = 'y';
char nic[12];
char name[10];
char gender = ' ';
char tel[10];

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("patientdetails.dat", "w");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Couldn't open file\n");
    return -1;
}
else
{
    printf("Do you want to enter record (y/n): ");
    scanf("%c", &order);

    while (order == 'y' || order == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Enter nic no.: ");
        scanf("%s", nic);

        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", name);

        printf("Enter gender (m/f): ");
        scanf(" %c", &gender);

        printf("Enter tel no.: ");
        scanf("%s", tel);

        fprintf(fp, "%s %s %c %s", nic, name, gender, tel);

        printf("Do you want to enter record (y/n): ");
        scanf(" %c", &order);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

return 0;
}
```

However, when I enter the info into the .dat file the gender shows up as a symbol instead and I just can't get around it.

[.dat file image. Gender shows as symbol not m for male](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpE4w.png)

edit:

This is my terminal input:

```
Do you want to enter record (y/n): y
Enter nic no.: 200007102766
Enter name: aruna
Enter gender (m/f): m
Enter tel no.: 0779426698
Do you want to enter record (y/n): n
```

The m for male, in the gender input shows up as a diamond with a question mark.

Hey, I wrote a c program to read my .dat file and it seems to work now. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `"%s %s %c %s"` -> `"%s %s %c %s\n"`. Anyway please [edit] and show  the patientdetails.dat file in your question as text.

Comment: I tried your code and the gender showed up fine in the file. Perhaps provide specifically in detail what you entered when you ran the program.

Comment: Candidates: 1) `char nic[12]; char name[10]; char tel[10];` too small (double their sizes) 2) Spaces in a name 3) **not checking** `scanf()` return value.  Post some sample input data here.

Comment: Using `scanf("%s", nic);` is bad/worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359).  Use a _width_ limit: `scanf("%11s", nic);`

Answer (score 2):

In the sample data that you show in the image, your `nic` and `tel` data appear to be too long to fit into their assigned variables - this causes ***undefined behaviour***!

If you need to store 12 actual characters in a `char[n]` string, you need to make `n` *at least* 13, so that there is room for the required `nul`-terminator.

So you will need to make both `nic` and `tel` larger arrays:

```c
char order = 'y';
char nic[13]; // 12 chars PLUS the nul-terminator
char name[10];
char gender = ' ';
char tel[11]; // 10 digits PLUS the nul-terminator
//...
```

You should also prevent the `scanf` calls from attempting to read too many characters for each string, by specifying a number in the `%s` format specifier; like this, for example (and similarly for the others):

```c
     scanf("%12s", nic); // Will stop reading after 12 chars have been scanned!
```

However, with this in place, any 'extra' characters given by the user will be left in the input buffer, and will thus 'overflow' into the next `scanf` call. You can prevent this by 'flushing' the input stream after each read. The most portable way to flush the `STDIN` stream, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7898215/10871073), is to define a macro like the following, somewhere *before* your `main` function, then just add `INFLUSH` after each `scanf` call. (There also are a number of other ways to effectively 'flush' the input stream, as discussed in the linked Q/A.)

```c
#define INFLUSH { int c;  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); }
```

And you would use it this like this:

```c
    scanf("%10s", tel); INFLUSH // Don't need semicolon after INFLUSH!
```

Comment: @Constalation "it doesnt seem to work" lacks information.  What was seen? what was expected?  Same as before?

Comment: Hey, Reinstate Monica, thank you for your response. I wrote a c program to read my .dat file and the gender seemed to show up. It works now. Thanks, and I'll make an edit!

Comment: @Constalation Glad it worked! But please read the extra information I've added in the edit.

Comment: Hey @AdrianMole thanks for the extra info, I made the adjustments to the char arrays, and I will surely read the extra info!